# Why does inputting the same number twice cause my program to fail?

Tags: java

I am just starting out learning Java and I am in the process of working through a much more efficient program to solve this problem, but I would like to understand why entering the same number twice causes the program to not run all the way through?

I need to write a program where the user enters three numbers and they get sorted in non-descending order.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModThreeReorder{
public static void main(String []args){

java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

int num1;
int num2;
int num3;

System.out.println("Please enter three (3) numbers");
num1 = input.nextInt();
num2 = input.nextInt();
num3 = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Thanks. You entered " + num1 + ", " + num2 + ", " +    num3 + ".");

if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3){
    if (num2 > num3 || num2 == num3){
        System.out.println("Your numbers in non-descending order are "  + num3 + ", " + num2 + ", " + num1 + ".");
    }
    else if (num3 > num2 || num3 == num2){
        System.out.println("Your numbers in non-descending order are " + num2 + ", " + num3 + ", " + num1 + ".");
    }
}
else if (num2 > num1 && num2 > num3){
    if (num1 > num3 || num1 == num3){
        System.out.println("Your numbers in non-descending order are "  + num3 + ", " + num1 + ", " + num2 + ".");
    }
    else if (num3 > num1 || num3 == num1){
        System.out.println("Your numbers in non-descending order are " + num1 + ", " + num3 + ", " + num2 + ".");


                }   
            }
else if (num3 > num1 && num3 > num2){
    if (num1 > num2 || num1 == num2){
        System.out.println("Your numbers in non-descending order are " + num2 + ", " + num1 + ", " + num3 + ".");
    }
    else if (num2 > num1 || num2 == num1){
        System.out.println("Your numbers in non-descending order are " + num1 + ", " + num2 + ", " + num3 + ".");

        }
      }
     }
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "causes the program to not run all the way through"? It doesn't exit? Exits without printing result? Fail with exception? What?

Comment: What problem are you facing? \any error, exception etc.

Comment: Your conditional logic is flawed, in that you aren't checking for all cases.  For instance, if I run your code with "1 2 2" as input, you check `if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3)` (nope), then `else if (num2 > num1 && num2 > num3)` (nope), then `else if (num3 > num1 && num3 > num2)` (nope), with no else clause, so your program exits.

Comment: Do you have some requirement that you conditionally check the order in this fashion, or are you allowed to use the better ways to do this that are built into the language?

Comment: i feel my post adequately answers your question

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean the buffer, try to place a `scanner.nextLine();` after each `nextInt()`.
This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line. Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly take three ints without clearing the buffer in some way. This is a friendly way i like to do it

```
System.out.println("Please enter number one :: ");
num1 = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter number two :: ");
num2 = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter number three :: ");
num3 = input.nextInt();
```

This will give you the results you expected.

Another flaw in your program is the logic in determining which number is the smallest. You should have something similar to this :

```
if(num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3){
    if(num2 >= num3)
        System.out.println(num3 +" "+ num2 + " "+ num1);
    else
        System.out.println(num2+" "+num3+" "+num1);
}else if(num2 >= num1 && num2 >= num3){
    if(num1 >= num3)
        System.out.println(num3 +" "+ num1 + " "+ num2);
    else
        System.out.println(num1 +" "+ num3 + " "+ num1);
}else{
    if(num1 >= num2)
        System.out.println(num2 +" "+ num1 + " "+ num3);
    else
        System.out.println(num2 +" "+ num1 + " "+ num3);
}
```

So putting this all together will allow you to take your three int inputs correctly, then sort and display them in descending order.